# Write reusable low level graphics library for emebedded device in ansi C

Tags: c, oop, pic, code-reuse

I have to write a low-level driver to manage a tft display for an embedded device.
Device is powered with a PIC24, 64K of ram and about 128K of program memory.

My intent is to write a generic graphics library where i will put all primitive graphics functions and a driver to send command and data to display.

Graphics lib uses the driver to access the display, but the display tecnology can change so the driver must be easily reimplementabile.

What is best way to write reusable code in this kind of scenario?

```
 -----------------          ---------------       
|                 |        |               |
|                 |        |               |
|    GFX_LIB      | =====> |    DRIVER     | ====> DISPLAY
|                 |        |               |
|                 |        |               |
 -----------------          -----/----\----
                                /      \
                               /        \
                         ----------   ----------
                        |          | |          |
                        | TYPE A   | |  TYPE B  |
                        |          | |          |
                         ----------   ----------
```

---

**More details**

This is a piece of code of my gfx lib

```
#include "Graphics.h"

void gfx_Init(uint16_t width, uint16_t height, uint8_t rotation){
    gfx_displayWidth=width;
    gfx_displayHeight=height;
    gfx_rotation=rotation;  
    displayDriverInit();
}

void gfx_setPixel(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint32_t color){
    displayDriverSendCommand(CHANGE_COORDINATE);
    displayDriverSendData(x);
    displayDriverSendData(y);
    displayDriverSendCommand(SET_COLOR);
    displayDriverSendData(color);
}
```

This is an hypothetical implementation of my graphics library.

Now, if i change driver, i'm really happy if i can reuse my gfx lib, and rewrite only display driver routines.
What the best way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: hi, this is for an embedded device with a picmicro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on what functionality your drivers will offer.

A minimal API could be declared like this:

```
typedef void* gfx;
typedef struct init_options {
  int display_width, display_height;
  //..etc..
};

gfx* gfx_init( init_options* opts );
void gfx_free( gfx* gfx );

// blit something onto sceeen
void gfx_blit( gfx* gfx, void* buffer, int buf_w, int buf_h, int trg_x, int trg_y, int trg_w, int trg_h );

// if you have double buffering (probably a good idea)
void gfx_swap( gfx* gfx );
```

Initialization, shutdown, mode-switching and blitting pixels onto screen may be all you need. Maybe you should also provide a fast SetPixel() routine. Everything else can be implemented in some kind of "GfxUtil" library, based on this.

Driver selection and implementation of this API may be handled by just linking the right library (where each library contains an actual driver, containing the actual code for blitting and so on).

**EDIT**

To have some dynamically replaceable code, your driver could be a struct with function pointers to actual implementation of driver specific code:

```
// common driver struct, used by gfx api
typedef struct driver {
    void (*init)( driver *driver, init_options* );
    void (*setpixel)( driver *driver, int x, int y, color color );
    //...
};

// driver constructor
driver* create_foo_driver() {
    driver* d = malloc( sizeof(driver) );
    memset(d,0,sizeof(driver));
    d->init = foo_init;
    d->setpixel = foo_setpixel;
    return d;
}

// some driver-specific code ...
void foo_setpixel( driver *driver, int x, int y, color color ) {
    // actual implementation
}

// API code calling driver code
void gfx_setpixel( gfx* gfx, int x, int y, color color ) {
   driver* driver = ((gfx_impl)gfx)->driver; // .. just an example
   driver->setpixel( driver, x, y, color );
}
```

Comment: Yes! yes this is very similar to my gfx lib, now the question is: what is best way to inject my tft-driver to send command and data to display and keep open the possibility that display tecnology can change and i have to reimplement the driver? I don't need(and don't want) reimplement all gfx library for each display i use.

Comment: @blow: provide more details please

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? Use [GD Graphics Library](http://www.boutell.com/gd/) to create an image in the display's image buffer. Or create an image outside of the display's image buffer and then copy the pixel data over once you're done rendering.

Note that GD is usually used to create image files (which a browser then downloads) but the rendering code is independent.

Comment: I need something like Graphics class of java, but for an embedded device with poor perfomance. And i know hot to write my primitive gfx function, i only need an advice how to build all for reusability...i'm new in C.

Comment: Have a look at the GD source code; it solves all your problems. You will probably need to extract a few files and delete the rest but you will be faster than writing everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much memory you can spare on your platform, you could use [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) which is structured exactly like you have drawn in your ASCII art. It is also implemented in C.

Comment: hi, i have only 64k of ram and about 128k of program memory, so i can only write a simple driver for primitive graphics function.

Comment: you should add that info to your question, low spec, low level graphics is a different kettle of fish

Answer (score 0):

Anyone Googling their way here should look at [Adafruit's GFX library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GFX-Library) and then see how their libraries for specific graphics drivers implement it. My experience is specifically with their [ST7735 driver](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-ST7735-Library) (which I ported to work on [chipKIT's PIC32](http://chipkit.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=2530) and is now getting help from experienced chipKIT developers). Perfect example of a C++ / OOP graphics framework that drivers for specific hardware can implement.

I'm surprised this question wasn't closed for being off topic like every other "how can I get this done" type of question lately.